# Hibernate c3p0 connection dies after few minutes of non use

Tags: java, api, hibernate, c3p0

I created an API HTTP trigger, that is connected to a remote database with Hibernate.
Once deployed locally everything works fine, but if the API is left unattended for a few minutes the connection dies.

How do I keep it active for longer periods?
This is my Hibernate config:

```
    final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    properties.put("jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    properties.put("jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getenv("SqlConnectionString"));
    properties.put("jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getenv("SqlUser"));
    properties.put("jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getenv("SqlPassword"));
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.testOnBorrow", true);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.validationQuery", "SELECT 1");

    properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.autoReconnect", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    //properties.put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", true);

    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 1000);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 1000);
    properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.handling_mode", "delayed_acquisition_and_hold");
    properties.put("hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.bytecode.provide", "javassist");

    //check it
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    // Connection pool
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", 5);
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", 50);
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", 4000);
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", 50);
    properties.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", 3000);
```

Comment: Increate timeouts.. there is a timeout that needs to be increaed for nonactivity.

Comment: It sounds like you allocate a connection, and try to use it continuously, instead of returning it to the pool for reuse, and acquiring a new one when needed. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes I do reuse the connection and no increasing the timeout doesn't solve the problem. So I should rather create a new connection each time the API is called and then immediately kill it?

Comment: Actually I don't believe my Connection Pool is even working